# Node js doesnt insert primary key in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, mysql2

How to insert primary key in node js table? Primary key is AUTO_INCREMENT, and as I know I should not pass anything from node js to DB for ID.

Here is my table:

```
`CREATE TABLE `table` (`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `post_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `author` tinytext NOT NULL)`
```

And here is my part of code for MySQL insert

```
dbConnection.query('INSERT INTO table (post_ID, author) VALUES (?,?);', [post_ID, author],
      (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      };
        return resolve(results.insertId);
    });
```

And still in my new row i got "null" for ID

Comment: Which npm package you are used for MySQL connection?

Comment: @GokulaKannan T, Express, mysql2

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the `PRIMARY KEY` is missing in the table creation.

Also, I would suggest using different name instead of `table`, which is currently present in the table creation query.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (id bigint(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, post_id bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, author tinytext NOT NULL);
```

With that above table, I can get the autoincrement id, I used the below snippet to do that.

```
connection.execute(
    'INSERT INTO tableName (post_id, author) VALUES (?,?);',
    [1212, "Third Author"],
    function(err, results, fields) {
      console.log(results); // results contains rows returned by server
      res.send("Inserted Successfully")
    }
);
```

Check the output below,

[image: Output]

Comment: This is full export of my table, as you can see, there is PRIMARY Key on "comment_id"

'CREATE TABLE `wpil_comments` (
                  `comment_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `comment_post_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                  `comment_author` tinytext NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_ID`),
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3867 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;'

Comment: Kindly let me know the MySQL version which you have installed in your machine?

Comment: 10.3.15-MariaDB

Comment: Then why do we use mysql2 instead of mariadb(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `post_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `author` tinytext NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY 
 (`ID`))
```

Comment: It is already like that, but still id is null on insert. It doesnt increment.